# sitemesh 3 safe to use in production?

Tags: templates, jakarta-ee, sitemesh

I'm new to decorators in java, i've discovered that sitemesh offers a good deal of simplicity and flexibility.I've noticed that the stable version 2 is not much in development(i might be wrong) and that there is a new website for 3 which is still in alpha.My worries is about using alpha code in production.Right now not sure if i will be stuck in 2 because no improvement or use 3 with its risks.

can anyone help? thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using alpha1 in production for some months now with no problems.
One of the sites has >5000 visits/day.
I only had to tweak the struts upload interceptor because it didn't work out of the box.

EDIT (2014.07.04)

I recently found out that sitemesh 3 is indeed NOT safe for production when used in Tomcat behind an Apache Server with ModJK. See the details here: ["Not Modified" header followed by unexpected content body with sitemesh3 and mod-jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430135)